# Using XlsxWriter in a Linux environment

Tags: linux, python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I am going to re-code a library from openpyxl to XlsxWriter. Does someone used XlsxWriter within a linux and Windows environment? Do you have encountered any problems by executing XlsxWriter within a Linux environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XlsxWriter works perfectly fine in a Linux environment (as well as Windows and Mac OS). Every commit is [tested on Linux](https://travis-ci.org/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter) for a range of Python versions.